# Google Dialogflow integration with GA4

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, integration, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I've been trying to connect google dialogflow chatbot with Google Analytics (GA4). Does any of you have it connected? When I try it, GA4 can't see chatbot on website due to Shadow DOM

Did you solve shadow DOM problem or did you find another way?

Comment: connect how exactly?

Comment: I want to track chatbot data (opens, how many messages were sent) and etc and have this data in GA4

Comment: You will probably have to go through the measurement protocol

Comment: Not sure this can help but there is an option in Dialogflow CX to export interactions to a BigQuery table. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/export-bq This might be a little overkill for you if you're just interested in aggregated metrics.  

There's also the Dialogflow internal analytics that can give you some insight about your chabot usage.